# WebControl Label is rendering like Span

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-controls

I'm tring to generate in codebehind next code:

```
<label class="switch">
      <input type="checkbox">
      <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Here what I tried:

```
Label lab = new Label();
lab.CssClass = "switch";
CheckBox inp = new CheckBox();
var span = new Label();
span.CssClass = "slider round";
lab.Controls.Add(inp);
lab.Controls.Add(span);
lab.AssociatedControlID = inp.ID;
```

I was searching and I found that to render label tag instead of span, you have to set AssociatedControlID and that is what I did, but is not working. Is rendering span label instead of label.

Thank you.

---edit----
This code in my aspx file is working, but my codebehind no.

```
<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="CheckID" ID="LabelID" runat="server" class="switch">
  <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckID" runat="server" />
  <asp:Label ID="SpanID" runat="server" class="slider round"></asp:Label>
</asp:Label>
```

Comment: Don't use `WebControls`. Use `HtmlControls`. `WebControls` are obsolete at best and take a big steaming poop all over HTML at worst. Using `HtmlControls` gives you more control over your markup - but ideally, just do everything directly with `HtmlTextWriter` in the `Render` method.

Comment: Thank you @Dai for your advice, but I can't change it to HtmlControls... There is a lot of code behind and it is not viable :\

Comment: You don't need to change anything to use `HtmlControls` - they all subclass `System.Web.UI.Control` so you can insert a `HtmlGenericControl` representing a `<span>` the same way your current code adds a `Label`.

Comment: Mmm..I have been tested and I have added System.Web.UI.HtmlControls library to avoid errors, but on return of my C# function my Label, I get an error because is not of the same type than WebControl...

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was that the inp.ID was null because it still wasn't be added. So what I did was generating a random ID on the input before defining AssociatedControlID attribute.